# Remove redundant text from the text containing redundancy on the election page

Tags: bug, election, wording

I was voting in the [Super User election](https://superuser.com/election/3), and noticed this in the sidebar:

> Each community member has 3 votes. Please cast your votes in order of preference, starting with the most desirable candidate first.

It bugs me that this says 'starting...first'. Could we instead have it say:

> Each community member has 3 votes. Please cast your votes in order of preference, with the most desirable candidate **first**.

or

> Each community member has 3 votes. Please cast your votes in order of preference, **starting with** the most desirable candidate.

Please?

Comment: The Department of Redundancy Removal Department will soon remove this redundancy shortly.